# Распознавание таблиц

Tags: opencv, распознавание-символов

Всем привет!
Периодически возникает необходимость распознать таблицу и извлечь информацию из ячеек.
Подскажите, плиз, куда копать? Можно ли для данных целей приспособить уже известные свободные пакеты (Tesseract, CuneiForm, ...) и если нет, то как сложно будет самому реализовать данное распознавание?

**Upd:** Начал изучение пакета OpenCV, очень похоже, что содержит необходимый мне функционал! Пример кода на Питоне:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: "то как сложно будет самому реализовать данное распознавание?" - очень сильно зависит от того, что распознаёшь и возможности наклона листа. Может быть очень просто, а может быть очень сложно. Это я про выявление границ ячеек.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, что-то типа такого, может кому пригодится ))

```
# Stan 2014-01-21
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.contour import ContourSet
import matplotlib.cm as cm

im = cv2.imread('d:\\doc3.jpg')

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

i = 0
for c, h in zip(contours, hierarchy[0]):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    print i, area, h

    x0, y0 = x1, y1 = c[0][0]
    for j in c[1:]:
        x2, y2 = j[0]
        lines0 = [ [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]] ]
        ContourSet(ax, [0], [ lines0 ], cmap=cm.cool)
        x1, y1 = x2, y2
    lines0 = [ [[x0, y0], [x1, y1]] ]
    ContourSet(ax, [0], [ lines0 ], cmap=cm.cool)
    i += 1

plt.show()
```